# Reattach a customer's quote to another customer

Tags: quote

Is there a way to reattach a customer's quote to another customer?
This is what I have tried so far. Setting customer via assignCustomer or setCustomerId does not do the job.

```
// load customer objects
$fromCustomerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(2637);
$toCustomerObj   = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(1923);

// load fromCustomer's quote
$quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($fromCustomerObj);

// add product to quote
$productObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(25227);
$quoteObj->addProduct($productObj , 1);

// reattach quote to toCustomer
//$quoteObj->assignCustomer($toCustomerObj);
//$quoteObj->setCustomerId(1923);

// save quote
$quoteObj->collectTotals();
$quoteObj->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be as simple as doing the following:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
              ->load(<new_customer_id>);

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
              ->load(<quote_id_of_old_customer>)
              ->assignCustomer($customer)
              ->save();
```

Note: if you execute the above code in a shell runtime, be sure to have previously set current store; it should match the one the cart is associated to:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(<quote_store_id>);
```

Hope this helps.